# A question about the Ancient Greek word 'πῦρ' in Arher Machen's "The Shining Pyramid"

Tags: meaning, nouns, non-native-english

Has anyone read this novel? I am quite puzzled.

*πῦρ* is the derivation of *fire*. Has *fire* anything to do with *Pyramid*?

Comment: Hi charlotte. Are you asking if *shining* is derived from *πνρ*? Can you clarify your question? You might have a wait, as most of us do not speak/read Greek, but a number do. Maybe they can help.

Comment: thanks a lot:) πνρ is the derivation of fire,this is true. But I do not know where does πνρ come from in the novel, because the writer never refer to it before. The shining pyramid is the name of the novel.

Comment: Please note: fire is _πυρ_ (pur/pyr), not _πνρ_ (pnr). Or am I misunderstanding what you mean by “the derivation of fire”?

Comment: Please edit to clarify how this is a question about English. Right now it is most explicitly not.

Comment: As Janus says, πυρ (pur/pyr) was the Greek word for "fire", and is directly cognate with the English word "fire". There is certainly speculation that it is involved in the Greek word for "pyramid", but this is not regarded as definite.

Comment: *meta*: Etymology of every other English word is the etymology of its source word in the parent language. Considering that, I guess this is on topic on ELU and naturally so.

Comment: It may be useful (even necessary) for you to quote the relevant text from the source, Arher Machen's *The Shining Pyramid*.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can clarify the meaning of this novel now.

Answer (score 2):

Stephen Mehler on *[gizapyramid](http://www.gizapyramid.com/mehler-originword.htm)* writes:

> The word pyramid is derived from the Greek words *PYRAMIS* and *PYRAMIDOS*. The meaning of the word Pryamis is obscure and may relate to the shape of a pyramid. The word Pyramidos has been translated as "Fire In The Middle".
>
> … the ancient Khemitians used the term PR.NTR, Per-Neter, for pyramid. …
> One of the main purposes of the Great Per-Neter was to generate, transform, and transmit energy. The Indigenous Wisdom Keepers of Egypt have provided us a concrete paradigm to support the power plant theory of Christopher Dunn. … if we support Dunn’s ideas that the energy reactions in the Great Pyramid took place in the so-called Queen’s and King’s Chambers, then certainly it was *Fire In The Middle*.

On the other hand, a research finding of Ferg Somo on [kaa-umati](http://www.kaa-umati.co.uk/pyramid_decoded%20part%202.htm) offers another interesting theory:

> This concept of ‘fire in the middle’ seems strange, but could the symbolism in resemblance between an erupting volcanic mountain and a pyramid be a valid supposition?

Comment: Thanks a lot :) You mean πνρ are the first three letters of the word pyramid. Ah! this explanation seems make sense.

Comment: @charlotte also you can use etymonline to look up [pyramid](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pyramid) which doesn't seem to support the 'fire in the middle' idea (but is not very explicit so I find doubtful).

Comment: @Mitch: the alteration of the Egyptian *pimar* to the Greek *pyramidos* may have been influenced by the fact that *pyr* meant *fire* in Greek.  But there's not going to be any evidence one way or the other. This would be much like the American settlers changing the Algonquin word *otchek* to *woodchuck*, which is a similarly-pronounced combination of English morphemes.